# Chang autocomplete-rails to search on all parts of string instead of just the beginning

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I've got some autocomplete fields where I'd the like the user to be able to enter any part of a search term to get the correct result.  For example, if they type "ang", they'd get angel and Los Angeles.   I tried changing the source to Array here with no luck:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
version: "1.10.2",
defaultElement: "<input>",
options: {
    appendTo: null,
    autoFocus: false,
    delay: 300,
    minLength: 1,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "none"
    },
    source: Array,
```

Do I need to make a change somewhere in the autocomplete-rails.js file?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change something on the rails end of things, since pattern matching like that won't be readily available client side. I would imagine that you will need to override the method that autocomplete uses to find its results to use something more like

```
City.where('name = ?, ["%#{params[:name]}"])
```

I'm not an expert in SQL, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was right in the doc for autocomplete-rails:


:full => true

By default, the search starts from the beginning of the string you're searching for. If you want to do a full search, set the full parameter to true.

```
class ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :brand, :name, :full => true
end
```

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete